# Android File Not Found Exception, though the image is saved

Tags: android

I am making an app which utilizes the camera, and has the ability to take a picture to use a simple image recognition API on it. I can use the gallery just fine to upload images, but straight from the camera is giving me massive issues. I have basically just copied the android dev documentation for most of the image creation, though may have needed to change some items here and there.

Here is the total code:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + "Image_for_Stack" + "_";
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "Camera");
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",   /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = "file: " + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    try {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.v(TAG, "IO Exception " + ex);
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContextOfApplication(),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Exception in dispatch " + e);
    }
}

private void galleryAddPic() {
    try {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        getContextOfApplication().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Exception " + e);
    }
}
```

And in a separate class, this is called:

```
public static byte[] getByteArrayFromIntentData(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent data) {
    InputStream inStream = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        inStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
        Log.v(TAG, "Instream works");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
        final ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        return outStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("FileOP Debug", "Exception " + e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            try {
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the image is created without issue. I can go to the emulator, look through the photo's app, and get:

[image: a photo with this info].

However, I get this error when the code gets to giving inStream a value:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file: 
>   /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/JPEG_Image_for_Stack_3248071614992872091.jpg
>   (No such file or directory) .

I don't exactly understand how this could be. The item clearly exists, and is saved on the phone. The app does request and is given the permission to write to external storage, and I have checked in the emulator permissions that it is given. Write also comes with read, so that shouldn't be an issue as far as I'm aware either.

### Edit

To show where this code is being called from.

```
        else if (requestCode == IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            galleryAddPic();

            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);

            final ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(getContextOfApplication());
            progress.setTitle("Loading");
            progress.setMessage("Identify your flower..");
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.show();

            if (!CheckNetworkConnection.isInternetAvailable(getContextOfApplication())) {
                progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getContextOfApplication(),
                        "Internet connection unavailable.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            client = ClarifaiClientGenerator.generate(API_KEY);
            final byte[] imageBytes = FileOp.getByteArrayFromIntentData(getContextOfApplication(), mediaScanIntent);
```

As of right now, imageBytes will be null as the the FileNotFound exception is thrown on that method call.

Comment: It is unclear where, when and how you call getByteArrayFromIntentData(). Do it inOnActivityResult() first.

Comment: Please tell the value of data.getData().toString().

Comment: @greenapps So the value of that is "file:///file%3A%20/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/JPEG_Image_for_Stack_4017640369874084193.jpg", and I put that right above the instream line in the third block of code. The error code is still the same, though the numbers are a bit changed as it is a new image being captured.

Comment: @greenapps That is already called from OnActivityResult(), I'll add the code to the post above.

Comment: `= FileOp.getByteArrayFromIntentData(getContextOfApplication(), mediaScanIntent);`. You should call it like `= FileOp.getByteArrayFromIntentData(getContextOfApplication(), data.getData());`.

Comment: `"file:///file%3A%20/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/JPEG_Image_for_Stack_4017640369874084193.jpg"`. ?? That is a pretty silly unusable path. But if you remove `"file:///file%3A%20` from it you end up with `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/JPEG_Image_for_Stack_4017640369874084193.jpg` which is quite usable.

Comment: @greenapps The problem with data.getData() is that it is a uri, instead of an intent, and that's why I was using the mediaScanIntent. Also, I have no idea where "file:///file%3A%20" even comes from. I assume that is what is screwing up the retrieval of the file? I never named it that, manually. Should I just manipulate that path by chopping off the first x characters from it?

Comment: Sorry not data.getData(). No.. Just data of course. As that is the intent you got and need.

Comment: @greenapps I guess I'll give up on this, as even Overflow is not suggesting I stop writing comments. I can call getByteArray with just 'data', but then, when setting the instream, data.getData() is always null, and therefore will cause a null pointer exception. I'm just not sure what exactly is happening anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code...

```
public class Images extends Activity
{
private Uri[] mUrls;
String[] mFiles=null;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{

    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.images);

    File images = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    File[] imagelist = images.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
    @override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
    {
        return ((name.endsWith(".jpg"))||(name.endsWith(".png"))
    }
});
    mFiles = new String[imagelist.length];

    for(int i= 0 ; i< imagelist.length; i++)
    {
        mFiles[i] = imagelist[i].getAbsolutePath();
    }
    mUrls = new Uri[mFiles.length];

    for(int i=0; i < mFiles.length; i++)
    {
        mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(mFiles[i]);   
    }   

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    g.setFadingEdgeLength(40);
}
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    int mGalleryItemBackground;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c)  {   
        mContext = c;   
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return mUrls.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        i.setImageURI(mUrls[position]);
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(260, 210));
        return i;
    }   
    private Context mContext;
    }   
}
```